# Word 2007 automatic lines from special characters

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

This is a feature that 2014 has but Word 2007 does not seem to, or I can't find it.

```
Type three dashes and you get a single line.
Type thee underlines and you get a bold single line.
Type three equal signs and you get a double line.
Type three asterisks and you get a heavy dotted line.
```

I can't get this to work, where do I set it up in Word 2007?

Answer (score 2):

Go to “Word Options” → “Proofing”, click on “AutoCorrect Options...”:

[image: AutoCorrect]

Go to the “AutoFormat As You Type” tab, and, under “Apply as you type”, click on “Border lines”.